# System.Environment in .NET Core 1.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Does anybody knows how to get information about current environment and platform in .NET Core?
Currently there are no Environment class in Core library.

[image]

Comment: @Andrei This is .NET Core: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/12/04/introducing-net-core.aspx

Comment: It's a static class and not a class that you new up. Maybe that's your confusion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`System.Environment` is available in the `System.Runtime.Extensions` package. Ensure you've referenced that package in your `project.json`.

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.0.10-*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Still they do not implemented yet "Is64BitOperatingSystem" property for .NET Core.

Comment: See also [dotnet/corefx#999](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/999) on GitHub.

Comment: I'm reporter of that issue :)

Comment: This refers to a now obsolete version of .net core