# Determine Operating System in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

How can I determine which operating system my .NET Core app is running on?
In the past I could use `Environment.OSVersion`.

What is the current way to determine whether my app is running on Mac or Windows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28664021/1009099 see this

Comment: Not really the answer i was looking for, but found it by myself.

Comment: `Environment.OSVersion` works in .NET Core 2.0+.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

### Method

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform()
```

### Possible Argument

```
OSPlatform.Windows
OSPlatform.OSX
OSPlatform.Linux
```

### Example

```
bool isWindows = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation
                                               .IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows);
```

### Update

Thanks to the comment by Oleksii Vynnychenko

You can get the operating systems name and version as a string using

```
var osNameAndVersion = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.OSDescription;
```

E.g. `osNameAndVersion` would be `Microsoft Windows 10.0.10586`

Comment: You can add that to get more information on OS there's another property in that package:
`System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.OSDescription` - returns description of OS with version, etc.

Comment: +1 although I do not like this answer. Why cant they just implement `System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform` for consistency?

Comment: Note that the constants do not represent all of the supported OSes. It is possible to probe for other OSes by using `IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Create("FreeBSD"))` whether they are supported now or may be added in the future. However, it is not very clear what a safe approach would be for what strings to pass (for example, does case matter, or does `"bsd"` match both `"FreeBSD"` and `"NetBSD"`?). See discussion about this feature [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1017).

Comment: Beware! `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform` does not look at the current OS but rather checks the build configuration target. Proof: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/OperatingSystem.cs#L91

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618677/56621

Answer (score 57):

Check `System.OperatingSystem` class it has static methods for each OS i.e. `IsMacOS()`, `IsWindows()`, `IsIOS()` and so on. These methods are available starting with .NET 5.

This makes it a great choice because the implementations for these methods use preprocessor directives to fix the return value to a constant true/false at compilation time for each target OS the `OperatingSystem` class is compiled for. There is no runtime probing or calls to make.

Here is an excerpt from one such method in `OperatingSystem`:

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates whether the current application is running on Linux.
        /// </summary>
        [NonVersionable]
        public static bool IsLinux() =>
#if TARGET_LINUX && !TARGET_ANDROID
            true;
#else
            false;
#endif
```

Comment: this should be the top answer

Comment: Only if you're targetting .NET 5 or later. The API unfortunately doesn't exist in .NET Core or any of the .NET Standards

Answer (score 50):

`System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform` can be used in full .NET Framework and Mono but:

- Mac OS X detection almost never worked for me under Mono
- it is not implemented in .NET Core

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation` can be used in .NET Core but:

- it is not implemented in full .NET Framework and Mono
- it does not perform platform detection in runtime but **uses hardcoded information instead**
  (see [corefx issue #3032](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3032) for more details)

You could pinvoke platform specific unmanaged functions such as `uname()` but:

- it may cause segmentation fault on unknown platforms
- is not allowed in some projects

So my suggested solution (see code bellow) may look sily at first but:

- it uses 100% managed code
- it works in .NET, Mono and .NET Core
- it works like a charm so far in [Pkcs11Interop](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/3.2.0/src/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/Common/Platform.cs#L228-L254) library

```cs
string windir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(windir) && windir.Contains(@"\") && Directory.Exists(windir))
{
    _isWindows = true;
}
else if (File.Exists(@"/proc/sys/kernel/ostype"))
{
    string osType = File.ReadAllText(@"/proc/sys/kernel/ostype");
    if (osType.StartsWith("Linux", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Note: Android gets here too
        _isLinux = true;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new UnsupportedPlatformException(osType);
    }
}
else if (File.Exists(@"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist"))
{
    // Note: iOS gets here too
    _isMacOsX = true;
}
else
{
    throw new UnsupportedPlatformException();
}
```

Comment: Appreciate for your effort. Wish there can be some consistency in the future.

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation should work correctly in full .net now (since November), so that seems to be the accepted "right" way now.  Not sure about mono, but since they are taking some code direct from .net now that it is open source, it's only a matter of time before it's working there, if not already.

Comment: Path.DirectorySeparatorChar Can be used to determine if its a windows or *nix machine.

Comment: InteropServices are very strange. Within VStudio and Rider, I sometimes get "Unknown in this context" or it compiles. No idea about the reason of this failure...