# How to get information about runtime .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-core-rc2

I have an app which works on Linux and Windows. I need to know where the app is working for use difference code. Thanks

Comment: try to use `RuntimeInformation` from `System.Runtime.InteropServices`: `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)` or `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)` or `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX)`

Comment: See my [detailed answer in other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38795621/3325704)

Answer (score 5):

You are probably looking for `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation` with the `IsOsPlatform` function to do runtime checks.

Have look at the video tutorial https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/aspnetmonsters/ASPNET-Monsters-Episode-46-Finding-Platform-Information of the ASP.NET Monsters.