# Path to LocalAppData in ASP.Net Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.Net Core application, and for the current purposes I've got to use LocalAppData.

Usually I would write `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`, but unfortunately it's not working with ASP.Net Core.

Could anyone help me with this?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Adem Caglin, I've found the solution.

The code I use:

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(
            RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) ? "LocalAppData" : "Home");`

Comment: refer this link : https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html

Comment: Is your ASP.NET Core application running with .NET Core libraries or the .NET Framework ?

Comment: @rboe I'm using .NET Core libraries

Comment: I came up with a [cross-platform solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57841780/1916816)

Comment: I came up with a [cross-platform solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57841780/1916816)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData");
```

ps: tested on windows

Comment: thanks a lot! but before I accept your answer, I've got to ask if there is some kind of workaround with Linux, which does not contain enviromental variable "LocalAppData". I thought about checking OS, and depending on it return either "LocalAppData" or "Home", but guess what? ASP.Net Core does not contain definition for Enviroment.OSVersion -_-

Comment: Getting variable for runtime platform  might be a solution. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39207282/how-to-get-information-about-runtime-net-core

Comment: `Environment.GetEnvironmentValiable( RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) ? "ProgramData" : "Home" );` or `"LocalAppData"` or `"AllUsersProfile"`  On windows they are all good to check out.  On Linux, `"HOME"` is about all you can count on.

Answer (score 6):

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)