# Cross platform way to get directory for application data in .NET Core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cross-platform, .net-core

At this moment I am writing a ASP.NET Core web application that should be able to run on Windows and Linux (Ubuntu 16.04). I have some data I want to store, but it is so little, using a database would be a huge waste of performance. Not to mention the installation procedure would be twice as long.

That's why I want to save this information in a file. In .NET Framework I would use something like `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` to get a directory where I can store my application files. [Unfortunately this method is not available in .NET Core 1.1](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder)).

**Is there any way to get a folder to write to, without hardcoding it?**

Below is an example of the data I want to write. There would only be about 5 devices at any time in this list.

```
<devices>
    <device>
        <id>0</id>
        <name>xxx</name>
        <physicaladdress>yyyyyyyyy</physicaladdress>
    </device>
    ...
    <device>
        <id>5</id>
        <name>xxx</name>
        <physicaladdress>yyyyyyyyy</physicaladdress>
    </device>
</devices>
```

Comment: The `App_Data` folder doesn't really make sense in .Net Core on any platform anyway.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224518/path-to-localappdata-in-asp-net-core-application)

Comment: @DavidG In Ubuntu for example it is quite common for applications to save their files in `/var/lib`. I was hoping for some directory like that.

Comment: Why not use some folder relative from the `IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath`?

Comment: There is no common folder for appdata in Linux/macOS/Windows. You have to determine the platform and load from/save to the appropriate designated appdata directory.

Comment: `/var/lib` is a global store for all apps on your system, even if the method returned that as a value, it wouldn't represent the same thing as `App_Data`. I would say that you're much safer doing a `#if <platform` directive.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I am going to use @HenkMollema answer. If I run into any permission issues, I will try with platform directives. Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually go with a folder relative from the `IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath`. It provides a cross-platform way to access files from the root of your application. You could even call it `App_Data` if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks! To get my final path, I used `string settingsPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "AppData");`

Comment: What if I want to install an ASP.NET Core application under `C:\Program Files`? Would `ContentRootPath` not then also be somewhere under `C:\Program Files` i.e. somewhere that log files cannot be written without privileged access? I'd want my logs to be written to somewhere under %APPDATA% for Windows, `$HOME/.local/share/` under Unix, etc.