# Alternative for LocalAppData environment variable on OSX

Tags: macos, .net-core

I'm just writing my first .Net Core application and am knocking into an issue on OSX.

I started writing this on PC and am just running some unit tests on OSX.

This line:

```
var localAppData = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData");
```

Returned the expected value on PC but returns `null` on OSX.  What would be the tidiest way to make this cross-platform?

Are there any additional considerations when applications are distributed in PKGs in terms of runtimes etc?

Many of the answers I'm finding in realtion to this talk about adding things to the launchd.conf which is all well and good for my development environment but what about when this is being run on a users machine?

What I'm trying is to find a way to retrieve some OSX equivalent of the Windows AppData.

A location where users applications can safely create files and store data that preconfigured on every OSX system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the cross-platform way of obtaining the path to the local application data directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113974/what-is-the-cross-platform-way-of-obtaining-the-path-to-the-local-application-da)

Comment: That's for Java.

Comment: yes, but as the question more related to OS behavior, it well explains what path you may use. And it also has link to [What is the OSX equivalent to Window's AppData folder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28928/what-is-the-osx-equivalent-to-windows-appdata-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'm using:

```cs
string GetLocalAppDataFolder() {
    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
    {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOCALAPPDATA");
    }
    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
    {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("XDG_DATA_HOME") ?? Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME"),".local","share");
    } 
    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
    {
        return Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME"), "Library", "Application Support");
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown OS Platform");
}
```

The logic is as follows:

- On Windows it returns the `LOCALAPPDATA` enviornment variable (usually something like `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local`).
- On Linux it returns the `XDG_DATA_HOME` enviornment variable, or if that's not available the `HOME` variable appended with `/.local/share` (as per the [FreeDesktop Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html))
- On MacOS it returns the `HOME` variable, appended with the path `/Library/Application Support` (so by default you'll end up with `/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support`

Comment: whats wrong with framework supported `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`?

Comment: (Seriously, I dont know, I always used this line, but never deployed on mac/linux)

Comment: @Jan'splite'K. I think it will work fine, but on OS X in particular it is more common for local application data to be stored in the path from Chris's answer.