# DinkToPdf Net Core not able to load DLL files

Tags: c#, .net-core, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, dinktopdf

I am trying to generate PDFs from HTML SQL server database using [DinkToPdf](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf) library.

In the startup file I have added:

```
var context = new CustomAssemblyLoadContext();
context.LoadUnmanagedLibrary(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "libwkhtmltox.dll"));
```

The line gives me this error on launching the web app:

> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\libwkhtmltox.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>
> System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.InternalLoadUnmanagedDllFromPath(string unmanagedDllPath)
>
> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\libwkhtmltox.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: Is it just okay if you import dinktopdf using nuget? insead of loading it directly as unamange?

Comment: Hello, I have imported. I have installed it well. In its description of use, I must import the dll files from the run. But this method Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() seems to not bet working on Asp.Net Core 3.0

Comment: Asp.Net Core Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() I think is the culprit here. It is returning C:\Program Files\IIS Express\ as the default folder for the project

Comment: [Farzaneh Talebi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2176905) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65773571) saying "I had same problem and this tutorial helped me: https://medium.com/volosoft/convert-html-and-export-to-pdf-using-dinktopdf-on-asp-net-boilerplate-e2354676b357"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some work-arounds. They are not perfect but worth a try, and they did do help and I was able to generate PDFs from SQl Server. I put the .dll files in the following folder and it worked.

> C:\Program Files\IIS Express

and the loaded the .dll files with

```
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "libwkhtmltox.dll");
```

The other way I went for the whole Path

```
context.LoadUnmanagedLibrary(Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\WebSolution\WebApp\libwkhtmltox.dll"));
```

Both of them worked. However, I urge Net Core developers to work on the GetCurrentDir very well. Or a Method to load from the Project or Solution Folder

```
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "libwkhtmltox.dll");
```

Comment: It does work locally,however when I publish to azure an error occured.

Comment: What of mac .   ?

Answer (score 13):

Just in case anyone else is having the same issue I was able to solve it by installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable.

Comment: I had a similar issue when loading a legacy 32bit dll in a UAT environment.  The C++ 2010 Redistributable worked for this particular dll.

Comment: Thx Very Much...local was ok but production - other serwer not working - YOU SAVE MY DAY

Comment: Wow, installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable works for me, here is the link to this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685

Comment: @LuqmanCheema We're sorry, this download is no longer available. - now what?

Answer (score 10):

It is mentioned in library's git repo that you should download binaries and include them in your source code:

> Copy native library to root folder of your project. From there .NET Core loads native library when native method is called with P/Invoke. You can find latest version of native library [here](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/tree/master/v0.12.4). Select appropriate library for your OS and platform (64 or 32 bit).

What was breaking things was that I was going to that url and right click on each file and select `save link as`(chrome). This leads to a broken file being downloaded:
[image]

DON'T DO THAT
you have to open each file within github and then use that `Download` button.
The healthy file is much bigger than what you would get if you go the wrong way!

[image]

ridiculous but the problem may be caused by this ...

Comment: I am using this solution, and it's now worked for me. So I just manually download the dll file, even I have libwkhtmltox.dylib and libwkhtmltox.so files.

Answer (score 2):

On Asp.Net Core application I use it like this to get the current directory on runtime

```
#if DEBUG
            //windows
            string filePath = $@"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)}\libwkhtmltox.dll";
#else
            //linux
            string filePath = @$"{(($@"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)}/libwkhtmltox.so").Replace(@"\", @"/"))}";
#endif
            CustomAssemblyLoadContext context = new CustomAssemblyLoadContext();
            context.LoadUnmanagedLibrary(filePath);
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));
#endregion
```

Comment: I would recommend using System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform() instead, check the platform if it's Windows or Linux and set the appropriate path. This way Debug won't be tied to Linux.

Comment: Also recommending this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/38795621/4745982. Works nice for all platforms

Answer (score 1):

if you are using asp.net core on Linux then you need to install required packages by using following command

```
apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    zlib1g \
    fontconfig \
    libfreetype6 \
    libx11-6 \
    libxext6 \
    libxrender1 \
&& curl -o /usr/lib/libwkhtmltox.so \
    --location \
    https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/raw/v1.0.8/v0.12.4/64%20bit/libwkhtmltox.so
```

Comment: this command need to be used by root permissions, we need to call 'sudo su' command before using this

Comment: following commands helped when DinkToPdf was not showing images properly

`sudo apt-get install libgdiplus`
`sudo apt-get install xvfb libfontconfig wkhtmltopdf`
`sudo apt-get install libc6-dev`
`sudo apt-get install openssl`
`sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev`