# DinkToPdf dll not found libwkhtmltox

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

I am developing a .net5.0 web api and i am getting the following error while using DinkToPdf:

> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libwkhtmltox' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

I have followed [this](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3605276/how-to-create-pdf-documents-in-aspnet-core-5.html) tutorial, with a few exceptions:

- added the service added the service, which was not done in the tutorial

  ```
  services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter),
           new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));
  ...
  services.AddScoped<IPdfService, PdfService>();
  ```
- named the services differently, but that shouldn't matter
- installed it via NuGet instead of `Install-Package DinkToPdf`
- my project is just an API, frontend is not in C#, shouln't matter sincer the error is here:

  ```
  return this._converter.Convert(htmlToPdfDocument);
  ```

Did everything else like in the tutorial.

Comment: check if its 32 or 64 bit and the same of your pool

Comment: @Aristos is there a way to get it to work without installing the libraries, as they didnt mention them anywhere on the site?

Comment: I do not know this library - I found this answer that may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430532/dinktopdf-net-core-not-able-to-load-dll-files

Answer (score 6):

What is happening there is you are missing the dlls under your project directory.
[image]

you can get them here [DinkToPdf dlls](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/tree/master/v0.12.4) and include them in your project.

Comment: Also, Don't forget to set copyTolocal to 'Copy if newer' in the properties.

Comment: The DLLs provided in the link are only for 32 and 64 bit systems. Will they work on Apples arm64 processors?

Comment: This solution works fine local machine (windows OS). But when deploying I got the same error. How can we deploy this library on Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 5):

For me adding this into the csproj file resolved the issue -

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="libwkhtmltox.dll" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="libwkhtmltox.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run below and it will install dlls into bin. Make sure copy those dlls into root directory

Install-Package DinkToPdfCopyDependencies -Version 1.0.8

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31839763)

Comment: no such package

Answer (score -1):

You can also try using this package to include the dependencies:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DinkToPdfCopyDependencies

Comment: doesn't exist..