# How to fix Azure app service unable to load DLL 'libwkhtmltox' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, dll, azure-web-app-service

Azure app service unable to load libwkhtmltox. I work fine on the local machine, But upon deployment to azure, I got an error that cannot load or one of its dependencies. I search online and made some changes to my code, I got this error again.

I got the error below when I push to azure again

> BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an
> incorrect format. (0x8007000B)
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.NativeLibrary.LoadFromPath(string
> libraryName, bool throwOnError)

Below is the updated code

```
            var wkHtmlToPdfFileDllName = "libwkhtmltox";
             if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
            {
                wkHtmlToPdfFileDllName += ".so";
            }
            else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
            {
                wkHtmlToPdfFileDllName += ".dylib";
            }
            else
            {
                wkHtmlToPdfFileDllName += ".dll";
            }

            var wkHtmlToPdfPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wkhtmltox", wkHtmlToPdfFileDllName);
            CustomAssemblyLoadContext context = new CustomAssemblyLoadContext();
            context.LoadUnmanagedLibrary(wkHtmlToPdfPath);
            services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));
```

I also added this to .csproj

```
  <ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="wkhtmltox\libwkhtmltox.dll" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="wkhtmltox\libwkhtmltox.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: "*I work fine on the local machine*" - how exactly are you running this locally, Docker?

Comment: I am not using docker on local and production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message,

To fix this issue you can try to set the platform target to **x86**   as below and then try to publish.

[image]

For more information please refer to this below links:

. [Unable to load DLL 'libwkhtmltox' | GitHub](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/issues/5)

. [BadImageFormatException |MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07d8370a-6121-4686-a6ad-c236e90df0cf/badimageformatexception?forum=csharpgeneral)

. [An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" even when the platforms are the same | SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-p)

. [DinkToPdf Net Core not able to load DLL files | SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430532/dinktopdf-net-core-not-able-to-load-dll-files)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this through changing the properties of the dlls files. You might wanna try it.

**1. Check Build Action**
For each DLL that you need to include in your deployment:

In Visual Studio, right-click the DLL in the Solution Explorer.

Select Properties.

In the properties window, find the "Build Action" setting.
Ensure that the Build Action is set to "Content".

**2. Copy to Output Directory**
Still in the DLL's properties window:

Find the "Copy to Output Directory" setting.

Set this to "Copy if newer" or "Copy always".

This ensures the DLLs are copied to the output folder during the build process.