# C# .NET 6 - how can I get OS Version like this "Windows 2019 Enterprise LTSC" without using System.Management?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I use .NET 6 to get os version.
I want to get os version like "Windows 2019 Enterprise LTSC" or "Windows 10 Professional".
I use `System.Management`:

```
string? info = null;
                using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"))
                {
                    ManagementObjectCollection information = searcher.Get();
                    if (information != null)
                    {
                        foreach (ManagementObject obj in information.Cast<ManagementObject>())
                        {
                            info = obj["Caption"].ToString() + " - " + obj["OSArchitecture"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    info = info.Replace("NT 5.1.2600", "XP");
                    info = info.Replace("NT 5.2.3790", "Server 2003");
                }
                return info;
```

I get os version wonderful,but `PublishTrimmed` was not allowed:
 `<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>`
`System.Management` was conflicted with `PublishTrimmed`.
I tried to use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Device.ComputerInfo`,but I need to change `.net6.0` to `.net6.0-windows` and add `<UseWindowsForms>true<UseWindowsForms>`.When I use this,I can not use  `<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>`.
For some reason,I need reduce my program size less than 20M.
I tried to use registry to get os version:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`
But in Windows 11 21H2,the key `ProductName` of the the value is `Windows 10 Pro`.It is not correct.
Does anyone have another solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine Operating System in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790802/determine-operating-system-in-net-core)

Comment: "For some reason,I need reduce my program size less than 20M." get rid of this totally arbitrary constraint?

Comment: @nviogt This is just a simple command line execution program. Maybe some people do not want an executable file to be more than 20M in size, which looks very bloated.

Comment: C and C# are very different languages. You should only tag language you are using.

Comment: @Gerhardh I apologize. I modified the Tags by mistake while editing

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen This method cannot obtain os version like “Windows 2019 Enterprise LTSC”.It's hard to distinguish the specific version of windows.

Comment: @JerryDora retracted my close vote for duplication