# Environment.UserDomainName equivalent in .NET Core console app

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-core

I need to determine the domain of the currently logged Windows user.
I don't see Environment.UserDomainName in .NET Core neither I was able to find any alternative. Is it hidden elsewhere?

This is not duplicate of [System.Environment in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497438) question as I have no problem with getting Environment class in .NET Core. I need its particular property UserDomainName which is missing there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Environment in .NET Core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497438/system-environment-in-net-core)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Environment.UserDomainName` is not available for .NET Core.

However, .NET Core does provide `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()`, which allows you to access environment variables. Since USERDOMAIN environment variable is available for Windows and HOSTNAME environment variable is available for Linux and Mac, you can call `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDOMAIN")` if its Windows, or `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOSTNAME")` if its Linux/Mac.

This class could be helpful:

```
public static class Machine 
{
    public static string User(){
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME") ?? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USER");
    }

    public static string Domain(){
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDOMAIN") ?? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOSTNAME");
    }
}
```

Can get easily the username and domain:
`Machine.User();` or `Machine.Domain();`

Comment: Thanks. And with the help of System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.Windows) I believe I'll be able to find out what variable to supply ("USERDOMAIN" or "HOSTNAME").

Comment: I didn't know about System.Runtime.InteropServices NuGet package until you mentioned it. Thanks for the tip!